# Python error when creating CLI entry point configuration for my project. What am I missing?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, program-entry-point, setup.py

I'm trying to create a cli entry point config for my python project. The project has the following structure:

```
/my_repo
    /my_project
        __init__.py (empty file)
        main.py
        menu.py
        database.py
        user.py
        utility.py
    /tests
    LICENCE
    pyproject.toml
    README.md
    requirements.txt
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
```

This is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    requirements = fh.read()

setup(
    name='My_project',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='John Doe',
    author_email='John.doe@test.com',
    license='MIT',
    description='CLI application.',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown"
    install_requires=[requirements],
    python_requires='>=3.10',
    packages=find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_project=my_project.main:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

This is the main.py:

```
from menu import menu

def main():
    menu()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = my_project
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = my_project

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    my_project = my_project.main:main
```

This is the pyproject.toml:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
```

After creating setup.py, setup.cfg and pyproject.toml, I installed build with the following command `pip install build` and after this I executed this command `python -m build` and at the end of the build I got the following message: "**Successfully built My_project-0.0.1.tar.gz and My_project-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl**".

At this point I tried to install the wheel with pip by executing this command: `pip install dist/My_project-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. The installation goes well but when I then try to execute the command to start the program I get an error:

command: `my_project`

**ERROR**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/johndoe/development/envs/my_repo/3.10/bin/my_project", line 5, in <module>
    from my_project.main import main
File "Users/johndoe/development/envs/my_repo/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from menu import menu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's my first time trying to create a CLI entry point configuration for a project (this is my first python project).
Hope the informations I provided are sufficient for the problem understanding.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the same issue I'm encountering when migrating to `pyproject.toml` from a traditional `setup.py`. Not sure why this error persists. I can access the module from my environment..

Answer (score 0):

Move entry point to pyproject.toml:

```
[project.scripts]
my_project = "main:main"
```

---

**Background:**

I had this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.../ci-checkout/venv/bin/ci-checkout", line 5, in <module>
    from src.start import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

File structure same as yours, only "src" as dirname for sources.
Build and install was successful, with pyproject having entry point:

```
[project.scripts]
ci-checkout = "src.start:main"
```

Solved by removing "src." from it:

```
[project.scripts]
ci-checkout = "start:main"
```

"ci-checkout" cli worked fine after that

Answer (score 0):

For the second one:

```
File "Users/johndoe/development/envs/my_repo/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/my_project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from menu import menu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'
```

Make sure menu.py contains "menu" class/function. Maybe there is nothing to import?

---

Also, try removing setup.py and setup.cfg and moving their contents (useful ones) to pyproject.toml. According to https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html those are 3 ways of configuring a package, where the last one is recommended. Might be that keeping all 3 together makes a mess.